# How do i program this arduino code

Tags: arduino

arduino code for programming a analoge pot to control 2 leds,1 to come on at 1.5V and the other other at 3.5v first time using this any help will do thanks

Comment: http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/HomePage http://arduino.cc/en/reference/homePage

Comment: 1.  If the pot signal goes “out of range”, eg > 4.75V or <0.25V it is deemed 
to be faulty and the system should stop operating  and both outputs should 
turn off. 
2.  Ideally the system will try maintain the height of the vehicle 
approximately ½ way between min and max, typically a pot value of 
approx. 2.5V. If the voltage is less than this the compressor should turn 
on. If the voltage is greater than this the exhaust value should turn on.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
#define LED1 4
#define LED2 5
#define POT A0

void setup()
{
    pinMode(POT, INPUT);
    pinMode(LED1, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(LED2, OUTPUT);
}

int val = 0;

void loop()
{

    val = analagRead(POT);
    if(val > 308)             // 1.5/max voltage (say 5) x resolution (1024)
        digitalWrite(LED1, HIGH);
    else if(val > 717)       // 3.5/max voltage (say 5) x resolution (1024)
    {
        digitalWrite(LED1, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(LED2, HIGH) ;
    } 
    else
    {
        digitalWrite(LED1, LOW);
        digitalWrite(LED2, LOW);
    } 
}
```

Fix some syntax errors, I am typing from cellphone.